# WPF Progress Bar PowerShell

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

I have been trying to get a WPF progress bar in to my PowerShell script for awhile now, but i can not figure it out. I have tried probably 13 different ways but to no avail. Here is my code:

```
$WPFRunQuick_Button.Add_Click({

 <#  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
    $Form.Text = "Processing"
    $Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",16,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    $form.Font = $Font
    $Form.Controls.Add($Label)
    $Label.Text = "You have run the quick test, please be patient as it runs."
    $Label.AutoSize = $True
    $form.autosize = $true
    $form.AutoScroll = $true
    $form.autosizemode = "GrowAndShrink"
    $Form.MinimizeBox = $False
    $Form.MaximizeBox = $False
    $Form.SizeGripStyle = "Hide"
    $form.startposition = "CenterScreen"
    $Form.Visible = $True
    $Form.Update() #>

    $max = 100
    For($i = 1; $i -le $max; $i++){
    Write-progress -Activity “Device Check” -Status “Testing, please wait.” `
    -percentcomplete ($i / $max*100) -id 1
    sleep 1
    }

    # Quick Test Run Function
      Quick_Test_Run

    # Prompt to send logs to associate support
    $a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell
    $intAnswer = $a.popup("Do you want to send these results?", 0,"Results",4)
    if ($intAnswer -eq 6) {
        $a.popup("Results Sent")

        # Create email
        $EmailSubject = "Tasa Test"
        $EmailTo = "usupportlogs@test.com"
        $EmailBody = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Temp\PMCS_TicketLogs.log")

        # Send email to usupportlogs inbox
        Send-MailMessage -From "PMCS_No_Reply@test.com" -To $EmailTo -subject $EmailSubject -Body $EmailBody -SmtpServer "SMTPRR.Cerner.Com"
    } else {
        $a.popup("Sending Cancelled")
    } 

    $Form.Close()

})
```

When i try to put one in before i call the quick test function, it will load all the way then launch the test, and if i put it in after it will do the test and then launch the progress bar. I just want a simple progress bar for this script. Any help or insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You don't post any code related to what you have tried for the progress bar, you seem to have posted everything else.

Comment: Edited script with example.

Comment: Without knowing what your quick_test_run is we can't really give you much help with this. If it is an external application then providing a progress bar is difficult enough that I wouldn't bother if it were me. If it is PS based then you just start the progress bar first, and as the test runs choose points through the script to update your progress bar, and close the progress bar after it is done.

Answer (score 0):

In a script I created recently, my GUI application would check availability of a series of computers in our corporate estate by iterating through a user-submitted list of IP Addresses (a `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` named in my script as `$boxIpInput`) and perform a `Test-Connection` conditional statement on each one. To allow the users to see what progress the scripts had made on the ping tests, I used a `System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar` to communicate the progress of the script; I found this out by googling for "Powershell Forms Progress Bar" and happened upon [this](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2014/02/18/progress-bar-to-a-graphical-status-box.aspx) link.

To create the `ProgressBar` object, I used the following code;

```
$barPingProgress= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$barPingProgress.Size= New-Object System.Drawing.Size(274,20);
$barPingProgress.Location= New-Object System.Drawing.Size(8,440);
$barPingProgress.Style= 'Continuous'
$barPingProgress.Value= 0
$objForm.Controls.Add($barKioskPingProgress);
```

Upon clicking the `$btnRunIpCheck` Button to perform the ping test, I used the input from `$boxIpInput` and piped it into a `ForEach-Object` loop to incrementally increase the count of the progress bar in a similar way to your For loop before the Quick_Test_Run function (I have removed all irrelevant code from the below snippet for brevity);

```
//other button initialisation code (removed)
...

$btnRunIpCheck.Add_Click({
    //some code to validate entries (removed)
    ...
    $arrTmpIpAddresses= $boxIpInput.Text.Split(" `n",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
    //some code to check size of list and warn users of the time it would take (removed)
    ...
    $arrTmpIpAddresses | ForEach-Object {
        $intOrderCount++
        [int]$tmpProgNum= ($intOrderCount/$arrTmpIpAddresses.Count) * 100

        $barPingProgress.Value= $tmpProgNum
        //ping test code (removed)
        }
    }
}
```

Personally, I would recommend using the `System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar` object over the `Write-Progress` method you're using at present; in the case of your code, you can either add the ProgressBar object as a part of the `Add_Click` event **or** have it created when you generate the main $Form object and then begin the Value incrementation during the `Add_Click` event.

To further help you, I'd need to understand what it is that you're counting the progress against - I can't really see what you're counting against (aside from the "Device Check" part that is) so I don't feel comfortable incorporating an example of how the ProgressBar Form would work in the context of your code. If you want me to help you further, you'll need to give me a little more detail. :)

Comment: So basically the check does numerous things: it checks last reboot time for device, does a group policy update, checks cpu usage, memory usage, performs a clear cache for IE, checks disk space, checks Bitlocker encryption, does a BSOD scan, McAfee DAT file check, java version check, and a Wi-Fi driver check.

Comment: So do you want to **A)** have a label to denote which process is executing and have the progress bar fill and reset to zero for each job, or **B)** to have the progress bar fill to denote the total completion percentage of all the jobs?

If the answer is A, you can just have the last action for each step to reset the progress bar to zero and evaluate percentage on a per-check basis. If the answer is B, you just divide the percentage by the number of jobs and then increment the percentage by that number.

Comment: Probably B for this case, but that does help a lot!

Comment: Okay great :) and do you have a way to measure each task? i.e. is there something you can iterate through? For some commands that are returning WMI data this may not be possible; in this instance, the easiest way to do that is just to add `$barProgress.Value= ( $barProgress.Value + ( 100 \ $NumberOfJobsTotal ) )` to the end of that particular section; that way, it increases the total of the ProgressBar without overwriting the initial value. You'll also probably need to supply the Value of `$barProgress` to the function and return that at the end to update the main script.